# Checking for unlimited internet access

Tags: c#

Some public wireless networks redirect you to a login page before giving you access to the internet. I want to test not only if the system has internet connection but also if it is unlimited, i.e. there is no redirect to such a login page.

I already checked the properties of `HttpWebResponse` to find something that could indicate this but found nothing.

How can I know that I'm not being redirected to a provider's login page?

Comment: You can't determine this.

Comment: Perhaps request a page with known content, ideally, one you control, and compare what you received against what it should be (the actual page content)?

Comment: Oli Charlesworth Windows can. When I login into a connection that requires authentication it notifies me in the tray.

Comment: What I think you are referring to is how the proxy server works at wireless hotspots. You wouldn't be able to detect that from the website end unless you attempted some reverse IP lookup magic and knew what IPs were hotspots/proxies. EDIT: Realised you meant from the client end, as what @zespri suggested would be the way to go.

Comment: zespri: yes, it's a way. i wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this

Comment: Like query some non-HTTP date from unusual port(s) on your site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intercepted by a proxy.  You'll have no idea how "nice" it is, don't expect anything like a 302.  So test it by visiting a known-good URL first, one whose response you can rely on.  Not Google, something you maintain.  If you don't get the expected response then you know that you've been redirected.

Comment: I always get the response. But it's from the proxy not from the url i requested. I could compare the expected response and the current response but I would like to know if there are more ways to do this.

Comment: Well, of course you test that you get the *exact* response you expect from that known URL.  Doesn't take more than a Hello World string.

Comment: Ok, i'll take this answer, but as long i dont maintain any website i dont have a true known-good URL. Credits to @zespri who suggested the same thing too.

Comment: [Info](http://erratasec.blogspot.com/2010/09/apples-secret-wispr-request.html) on the known good URL that Apple uses.

Comment: This post talks what I was looking for, but exposes the problem of just test a URL. If for some reason the URL goes offline or returns something I dont expect my test will not work. Anyway, if Apple choose this way to check connection, i can do the same.

Comment: @matheusrufca, there are a ton of ways to get a site up that costs you $0.  For example, Amazon AWS has a free tier that would work just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another version of you can't do this:

You can test if you have access to whatever site you're testing as a reference.  That doesn't prove you have unrestricted access, though.  You might be behind a firewall that blocks out large swaths of the internet (for example, a corporate firewall blocking a bunch of places employees like to waste time but which have no job-related purpose.)

You might be behind the Great Firewall of China that will reset your connection if it doesn't like the domain you're accessing or if it sees words it doesn't like.

You might even be working through an evil ISP that replaces ads with it's own ads.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. As a trivial example, my service provider does not alter my connection or require any special login procedure, but if I use more than my allocated amount I will be charged for it.